# Backslash in formula before close parenthesis: what does =ISNUMBER(A1\) mean?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Today, I had a typo when I wrote `=ISNUMBER(A2\)`. I expected Excel to complain, but it didn't - instead, it calculated the formula as if the backslash wasn't there. This works for some functions but not others. `=COUNTIF(B:B,A2\)` works, but `=LEN(A2\)` throws an error. It only seems to work for a range reference or name followed by a close-parenthesis for certain functions.

Why isn't Excel throwing an error here? Is there some functionality I'm not aware of, or some other purpose to this notation?

Comment: From what I can see in Evaluate Formula is that `A2\\`` converts to a `#Name?` error.  The `COUNTIF` is then counting cells that contain that error.  `ISNUMBER` is always return FALSE as the error isn't numeric.  `LEN` is expecting text or a cell referencing, but is getting an error instead so is also returning the error (I guess).

Answer (score 1):

Turning @Darren Bartrup-Cook's comment into an answer, `A2\` gives a `#NAME?` error, but `ISNUMBER()` can process `#NAME?` errors and the results were coincidentally the same as what I was expecting. I never actually checked whether my formulas depended on cell A2 the way I thought they did.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, the backslash is used as one of several escape characters; in particular, it is used in custom formatting strings to produce literals.

Another function that involves the usage of backslashes *specifically* within the scoping of formulaic inputs would be Excel's `name`  management feature, in which backslashes are legal characters (in fact, they are otherwise unrecognized by Excel formulas).  This leads me to the following conjecture:

- When inputted into a formula, outside the syntactical scoping of custom data formatting or escape sequencing...

  - Excel does not recognize "\" as a special character (only as an escape character).
  - Excel only recognizes "\" as part of a `name` .
  - Therefore, in all cases where "\" is used, Excel interprets the input as a `name` reference.

To support my conjecture, you can observe the formula evaluation for each of the formulas you've cited: `=ISNUMBER(A2\)` `=COUNTIF(B:B,A2\)` `=LEN(A2\)`.  Notice that upon evaluation, ***all three functions* result in a `#NAME?` error**.

Now, to answer the other portion of the OP: why do the functions appear to handle the error in inconsistent fashion?  Here, I once again propose a personal conjecture: I believe it has to do with the functions themselves, or more specifically, the categorical grouping of Excel's functions.

Within Excel **specifically**, the `LEN()` function is gated under the `TEXT` function category, i.e., it is treated as a **string manipulation or query function**.  When an error occurs for this category of functions, it can only throw an exception (in most standard use cases).

On the other hand, both `ISNUMBER()` and `COUNTIF()` are gated under the `LOGIC` function category, i.e, they are **conditional evaluation functions**, which also relate to **Boolean functions**.  Now, as it so happens, there is a particular behavioral convention that is commonly observed across several major programming languages, (e.g., Python, etc): a Boolean `FALSE` can be expressed as a numeric `0`, just as a Boolean `TRUE` can be expressed as a numeric `1`.  This supposedly takes influence from the nature of binary representation for TRUE or FALSE being represented as 1 or 0, but in the context of `ISNUMBER()`, the expected output is **purely Boolean**, whereas the expected output for `COUNTIF()` is **numeric but also Boolean** (disclaimer: the latter conclusion is purely based upon my own speculation).  In support of my conjecture, if you input a number into cell `B1` and then name cell `B1` "A2\", notice that all three functions will immediately change their outputs:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: this doesn't explain the answer

Comment: I have edited my answer to explain the functional output behaviors.